# Hosting Craft on Heroku, problems with Asset uploads and thumbnail generation

Tags: assets, server, upload

Has anyone had success hosting Craft on Heroku? I got it up and running, but can't get file uploads to work. Also image thumbnails don't get generated. I am using Craft PRO and Assets are hosted on Amazon S3. I understand that you can't upload assets to Heroku, I thought using S3 should be sufficient to circumvent that fact.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting it up and running at all -- can you offer any suggestions or give any kind of walkthrough?

Comment: @adrienne, please ask a detailed question of your own.

Comment: Florian: it's not worth it to me; I'll just give up on Heroku if there's not a walkthrough available somewhere.

Comment: @adrienne lookie here :D https://medium.com/@aj1215/craft-cms-on-heroku-79b991665b0b

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting the client_max_body_size to, in my case, 20M.

Did this using the following nginx_app.conf

```
location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
}

location @rewriteapp {
    # rewrite all to index.php
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?p=$1 last;
}

location ~ ^/(index)\.php(/|$) {
    client_max_body_size 20M;
    fastcgi_pass heroku-fcgi;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
}
```